# How to get value of numeric datatype in ado.net from SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I am writing application with ADO.NET and want to select a value which is of type `numeric(9, 2)`. But I don't know how to use this value, I mean I'm not able to cast this value.

So to which datatype it should be casted to.

```
Decimal decimalLastModifiedWaitingForApprovalcurrency = 0;
decimalLastModifiedWaitingForApprovalcurrency = (Decimal)(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

I have tried this also

```
Convert.ToDecimal(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

I have considerred that this could be casted to `Decimal`, But its giving error.

So whats numeric equivalent of SQL server numeric datatype in C#?

Comment: what is the error you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `ExecuteScalar()`, it is returning the value as `object`. If you aren't quite sure what CLI type it has chosen, just look at:

```
object value = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
Debug.WriteLine(value.GetType().Name);
```

Comment: Great Marc. Welcome back :)

Comment: @Murali did I ever leave?

Comment: No. But i am a fan of reading your answer and learing c#, LINQ. :) I read your post after long time.. A ton of thanks :)

Comment: Thanks Marc, I have found the issue. Actually I want to get the value from 3rd column, but executescalar returns 1st column from the row. that is why it was giving error of wrong cast. If I want to get the 3rd column value from the row in that case how can I get that value using executescalar? Do you have idea

Comment: @vivekjain `ExecuteScalar` **only** returns first column, first row, first grid; if you need something more, use a different query API - maybe `ExecuteReader`, or maybe something like "dapper" that would wrap it up for you

Answer (score 1):

`Decimal` only. You are using correct data type.

Check the complete list [`SQL Server Data Type Mappings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

try `Convert.ToDouble(cmd.ExecuteScalar());` and let me know if this does not work.